# Are CFD stock shares anonymous?

Tags: cfd

I'm not an expert in the stock market but I've a question.

Are CFDs anonymous or how do stock market listed companies identify their investors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Companies only know about shore *owners*. They do not know about owners of CFDs or other derivatives like options.

Remember that if you trade a CFD you do not own the stock - you enter into a *contract* to pay the difference between the stock price and some set value in the future.  You are not investing in the company - you're making a *bet* about where the stock will go.